# Block jerks when changing its margin-left/left in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

The task is to keep the block visually at the beginning when scrolling.
In Chrome, there are no problems, the block moves smoothly without jerking.
Have problem in Firefox

Tried through:

```
 1. margin-left: Xpx;
 2. transform: translateX (Xpx);
 3. left: Xpx;
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem and how was it solved?
Firefox Version 90.0

[codepen](https://codepen.io/koshik/pen/ZEKxqYv)

Comment: Uh... `position: sticky; left: 0;` and remove all JS???

Comment: This helped to solve the problem.
But still it is not clear why there is a twitching with my way in the moss

Comment: [codepen](https://codepen.io/koshik/pen/eYWrgyq)

Comment: It "twitches" because you're trying to change rendering elements while those rendering elements are moving and there's no guarantee it'll stay in sync.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that Mozilla is a terrible browser.
The twitching was repeated on both 70 and 90 versions.